# Script: Running a second process when the firts ended

Tags: scripting, process

I am trying to make a script that consist in a two parts. the first one is to run a initial state and the second one is to equilibrating the system. The problem is that the second is dependent of the first so i need the first process to be ended before i run the second one. How can i do that?

the code that i'm running is the following:

```
#!bin/sh

echo -n  "Imput Chemical Potential:"
read chem
awk < towhee_input -v n="-$chem" 'NR==12 {$0=n}{print}'> towhee_input1
echo -n  "Imput nstep initial:"
read nstepi
r=5
declare -i p
pi=$nstepi/$r
awk < towhee_input1 -v k="$nstepi" 'NR==18 {$0=k}{print}'> towhee_input2
awk < towhee_input2 -v t="$pi" 'NR==22 {$0=t}{print}'> towhee_input3
awk < towhee_input3 -v t="$pi" 'NR==24 {$0=t}{print}'> towhee_input4
awk < towhee_input4 'NR==82 {$0=".true."}{print}'> towhee_input5

##### (i wont that process finish first and then continue the script)
towhee towhee_input5 > output &  
##### (i wont that process finish first and then continue the script)

cp towhee_final towhee_initial
echo "Run again?"
read wwwww

u=5
declare -i nstep
nstep=$nstepi*$u
declare -i p
p=$pi*$u
awk < towhee_input5 -v k="$nstep" 'NR==18 {$0=k}{print}'> towhee_input6
awk < towhee_input6 -v t="$p" 'NR==22 {$0=t}{print}'> towhee_input7
awk < towhee_input7 -v t="$p" 'NR==24 {$0=t}{print}'> towhee_input8
awk < towhee_input8 'NR==82 {$0=".false."}{print}'> towhee_input9
towhee towhee_input9 > towhee.prod &
```

how can I accomplish that ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to clarify what you want to ask, it's really unclear. delimite your script from your command line and what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the `&` at then end of

```
towhee towhee_input5 > output &
```

In shell `&` means to put in background execution, if you want you process to run in foreground then just remove it and your script will go one once it ends.

#### edit

If you want to run the command in background and wait for it, then simply use `wait`

```
towhee towhee_input5 > output &
wait
continue your code...
```

it should be sufficient, though this code would wait for every command you launch in background before, you can use also `wait $!` because `$!` is a variable that contains PID of the most recent background command and `wait` bash built-in command is usually used with a PID as argument to wait for a specific process.

Comment: Thanks!! but can i running the process in background and still make what i wont?

Comment: @JoaoMacau see the edit ;-)

Comment: thanks :) its running!! do you now you i can use the promp line wile i am waiting for the first process to end?

Comment: @JoaoMacau when you launch a command put `&` at the end so the command will run in background and leave your shell accessible